# Charting, or news to trade?

Tags: stocks, trading, news

Can someone say if traders / investors use the news as a primary way to buy/sell shares, please? It's just that I read another post stating that they do not go by the news and use charting... so not clear on this.

As I'm not too familiar with charting I would opt for the news.

Would welcome your view to confirm mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Investors and traders use a variety of ways to make their trading decisions:  Fundamental analysis,  technical analysis, news,  newsletters, brokerage advice, whatever.  Some even use astrology.  Others just decide on an allocation and plow money in regularly without any clear strategy.

What others use to make their investment and/or trades isn't as important as figuring out what suits you and which method facilitates it.

Comment: Is there a known resource for the latest UK news (ideally filterable), maybe a single source?

Comment: Sorry but I'm in the USA so I don't know what's available in the UK.  I'd guess that they have similar or the same as our DJIA Streaming News,  Bloomberg, etc.  A decent broker also provides real time news.  In terms of filtering, a long time ago I subscribed to DJ News.  It offered a 100 symbol list for color coding news highlights.  I have no clue what's out there now.